# Using BRE and ERE in awk

Tags: awk, regular-expression

How does `awk` distinguish between use of `BRE` versus `ERE` ?  For `sed` there is the `-E` option one can use.

Comment: Get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to start learning about awk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not need to distinguish between the two since regular expressions in `awk` are always POSIX *extended* regular expressions.

From [the POSIX specification for `awk`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_04):

> The awk utility shall make use of the extended regular expression notation [...]

I'm not aware of any `awk` implementation that introduces a non-standard option for switching to POSIX *basic* regular expressions.

The `sed` utility always uses POSIX *basic* regular expressions unless you use it with its (so far) non-standard but fairly commonly available `-E` option.  The `grep` utility also defaults to POSIX *basic* regular expressions, but the `-E` option that enables it to use POSIX *extended* regular expressions is actually standard (while `-P` for Perl-compatible regular expressions, PCRE, is non-standard and not commonly implemented on non-GNU systems).  The `grep` utility can additionally interpret the given expressions as plain strings with its standard `-F` option.